# Configure a domain alias

Tags: networking

How do i configure a domain alias in ubuntu?

I have a server called example.com which has a git running on port 4321
Port 4321 is not visible to the outside world.
So from machine1 I use ssh to connect to example.com forward port 4321 to localhost i.e. ssh example.com -L4321:localhost:4321

From machine I would like execute a command:

git clone ssh://example.com:4321/myproject

is there a way of making example.com point to localhost on machine one? So that the above git command behaves as though it was the following command:

git clone ssh://localhost:4321/myproject

I don't have any services listening on port 4321 on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do this for various build tools (Jenkins, etc) and local dev sites.
First you want to edit your host file here,

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

There should be at least two lines already, one for localhost and another for you machines name. Now get the internal IP of the machine running your service(s) and add a new entry.

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    MyMachine
192.168.1.2    example.com
```

Don't forget when you add `example.com` to the host file, if it was for example `askubuntu.com` instead you would reach your machine with the IP you entered, on port 80.
Obviously this will only route that name (example.com) on your machine with the hosts file.